# Use remote fonts (typeface)

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-typeface

I need to use external fonts for my Android app. I receive the URLs for the fonts in a JSON object on app start, and then I have to use these fonts for my TextViews and Buttons.

What's the best way to proceed? I assume I have to download the *.otf files, but where can I download them? Is it possible to store them in internal storage so that I don't have to request external write permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where can I download them?

Internal storage (`getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`, depending on your preference).

> Is it possible to store them in internal storage so that I don't have to request external write permissions?

Sure. Other apps do not need access to the fonts for you to use them in your widgets.

I do not know who is choosing the fonts, but make sure they do adequate testing: all fonts on all Android OS versions that you are supporting. Android's font support has changed over the years, and while it is better now, on older devices some fonts are quietly ignored, as the system has problems loading the font.